# Run program until a specific condition is met?

Tags: java, char, user-input, infinite-loop, break

I want this code to keep running, as long as the user keeps inputting 'Y' or 'y' when prompted, any other input should quit out of the program. As my code is now, it only runs one time no matter what is inputted. How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class zigzag {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScanner, sc;
        myScanner = new Scanner(System. in );

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer between 3 and 33: ");
            int nStars = myScanner.nextInt();

            if (nStars > 33 || nStars < 3) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, this input is out of the accepted range");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < nStars; i++) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < nStars - 2; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                for (int k = 0; k <= j - 1; k++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println("*");
            }
            for (int g = 0; g < nStars; g++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");

            System.out.print("Enter 'Y' or 'y' to go again: ");
            char ch = myScanner.next().charAt(0);

            if (ch != 'y' || ch != 'Y') {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of having an if with the condition, you add that condition on the while loop, and maybe change it to a do ..while

Comment: Please learn to format your code, this is illegible.

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
if(ch!='y' && ch!='Y'){
```

not

```
if(ch!='y' || ch!='Y'){
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ch!='y' || ch!='Y')
```

will be true always.

Change `||` to `&&` instead so that it looks like:

```
if (ch!='y' && ch!='Y')
```

Comment: But I don't want the program to exit if ch does equal y or Y

Comment: @Clarisa right, I thought you would like to finish with 'Y' -  I corrected this

Answer (score 0):

The `if` condition is wrong - it will always evaluate to `true`. Since a character can't be both `y` and `Y` simultaniously, it will **always** be "not equal to `y` or not equal to `Y`.

Instead, you need a condition that checks if the character is not equal to `y` **and** not equal to `Y`:

```
if( ch!='y' && ch!='Y') {
    break;
}
```